# I need to figure out how to make my program repeat. (Python coding class)

Tags: python

I am a beginner student in a python coding class. I have the majority of the done and the program itself works, however I need to figure out a way to make the program ask if wants a subtraction or an adding problem, and if the user would like another question. I asked my teacher for assistance and he hasn't gotten back to me, so I'm simply trying to figure out and understand what exactly I need to do.

```
import random

x = int(input("Please enter an integer: ")) 
 if x < 0:

    x = 0

    print('Negative changed to zero')

 elif x == 0:

    print('Zero')

 elif x == 1:

     print('Single')

 else:

     print('More')    

 maximum = 10 ** x;
 maximum += 1
 firstnum = random.randrange(1,maximum)       # return an int from 1 to 100

 secondnum = random.randrange(1, maximum)

 compsum = firstnum + secondnum           # adds the 2 random numbers together

#  print (compsum)                       # print for troubleshooting

 print("What is the sum of", firstnum, " +", secondnum, "?")    # presents problem to user

 added = int(input("Your answer is: "))   # gets user input

 if added == compsum:                     # compares user input to real answer

   print("You are correct!!!")

 else:

   print ("Sorry, you are incorrect")
```

Comment: [`while` loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) will be helpful.

Comment: I had something like this in mind for the loop but question loop but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Comment: `playing = True
while playing:
    choice = input("Would you like another question? y/n: ")
    if choice == "n":
        print "Thanks! Have a good day!"
        playing = False
    else:
        print "Giving another problem!"    `

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
def foo():
    print("Doing good work...")

while True:
    foo()
    if input("Want to do more good work? [y/n] ").strip().lower() == 'n':
        break
```

I've seen this construct (i.e., using a `break`) used more often than using a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) in Python, but either will work. The sentinel version looks like this:

```
do_good_work = True

while do_good_work:
    foo()
    do_good_work = input("Want to do more good work? [y/n] ").strip().lower() != 'n'
```

You'll want to do more error checking than me in your code, too.

Comment: I tried something similar to the first code "the def quest()" one and I couldn't get it to properly string, it simply said there was a syntax error but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Packy502 If you're using Python 2, you'll want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. The above code is for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Asking users for input is straightforward, you just need to use the python built-in input() function. You then compare the stored answer to some possible outcomes. In your case this would work fine:

```
print('Would you like to test your adding or subtracting skills?')
user_choice = input('Answer A for adding or S for subtracting: ')
if user_choice.upper() == 'A':
    # ask adding question
elif user_choice.upper() == 'S':
    # ask substracting question
else:
    print('Sorry I did not understand your choice')
```

For repeating the code `While` loops are your choice, they will repeatedly execute a statement in them while the starting condition is true.

```
while True: # Condition is always satisfied code will run forever
    # put your program logic here
    if input('Would you like another test? [Y/N]').upper() == 'N':
        break # Break statement exits the loop
```

The result of using `input()` function is always a string. We use a `.upper()` method on it which converts it to UPPERCASE. If you write it like this, it doesn't matter whether someone will answer N or n the loop will still terminate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the possibility to have another question asked use a while loop and ask the user for an input. If you want the user to input whether (s)he want an addition or substraction you already used the tools to ask for such an input. Just ask the user for a string.